# dynamic-require in DrRacket

Tags: racket

I am experimenting with the **2htdp/planetcute** library given in racket's documentation.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpPlanet_Cute_Images.html

When I try to use its objects like "**character-boy**". It gives me that the **dynamic-require** is set to #f instead of 0.

So, there is a procedure called:

```
(dynamic-require mod provided)
```

Where, **mod** = module path and **provided** = value.

So, I ran this:

```
(define path (string->path /usr/shared/...../character-boy.rkt))
(dynamic-require path 0)
```

And then, I was able to use **character-boy** which returned an image. I am not able to find a procedure that does this for all .rkt files in a folder.

There are like 40-50 .rkt files and it looks like I have to write 40-50 **dynamic-require** procedures. Is there a simple folder **dynamic-require** method???

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your question, but why not just use `(require 2htdp/planetcute)` instead? That is the usual way that you import a library in Racket.

Comment: I did do that. Even though I did that, it says the dynamic-require is set as #f. After I did the (dynamic-require path 0) for the path of character-boy.rkt, I could see the boy image. Before, it gave the #f error.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I get the same error if I try to refer to `character-boy` from DrRacket's interactions area. It works for me if I reference it in the definitions area first. This looks like a bug in the library or in Racket. Until it's fixed, you should be able to use that workaround.

Comment: Yeah. I though maybe there is a solution that I didn't know of. I am actually trying to create another set of my own images and design a game. Just wanted to see how I can manipulate the images but came across that error.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this problem is now fixed in the latest version of Racket (by this commit: https://github.com/plt/racket/commit/414507699ba8f71a7b3630b833a4b4582a49dd57). You should be able to just use `require` normally.

If you'd like to try the fix, you can download a pre-release build from one of the build sites linked from here: http://pre.racket-lang.org/

Or you can wait until Racket v6.0.1 is released in a few weeks.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot for the update and thanks for hanging onto it.